# trying to optimize wordpress page with css font-display

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a blog using WordPress and altervista how domain. My question how I can show immediately the text when my page is loaded? I have tried this but it doesn't work because Altervista see it how an error. Thanks a lot for answer.

```
@font-face {  
   font-display: auto;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you asking for.. No idea what you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to riduce the time that the page use to charge the text.

Comment: https://varvy.com/pagespeed/render-blocking-css.html
this is an overview about techniques. be aware that this is often a trade-off - the fastest load time could mean that the page does not load nicely for the visitor (changing fonts, distribution, etc after loading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to upload the fonts to your site and link to them from your CSS.  You can use Font Squirrel's free [Webfont Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to get all modern versions of the fonts needed.  This will ensure cross browser visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fixing the Flash of Invisible Text (FOIT) and trying to add `display=swap` to google fonts then add this code in your child theme's `functions.php` file.

```
// Add display=swap to every font call to google
function add_swap_to_fonts_from_google_etc( $html ) {
    if ( TRUE == strpos( $html, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family' ) ){
        return str_replace( 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?display=swap&', $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'add_swap_to_fonts_from_google_etc', 10 );
```